# Flask, dc.js, d3.js and loading data

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask

I'm trying to get a small website with data visualization running, but I can't figure out how to do it. The website should have `www.example.com/formular?key1=val1&key2=val2` or `www.example.com/formular/val1/val2` format and show a visualisation according to search variables given in the formular.

I have a `data.html` where the jsonfile can be fetched and a `formular.html` where the user can input what kind of data (`search`) he/she wants and the number of entries (`limit`).

The **Flask** code is

```
@app.route("/data")
def data():
  search = request.args.get("search","co3")
  lim = request.args.get("limit",10)
  return somefunc_json_return(search, limit)

@app.route("/formular")
def formular():
  return render_template("formular.html")
```

- How can I give the javascript the correct address? With `url_for`? I tried that but it gives me an `Could not build url for endpoint 'formular' with values ['search']. Did you mean 'static' instead?`